# How do I find the transitive closure of a relation and the partition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Set =
{a,b,c,d,e}

R = {(a, c),(b, d),(c, e),(d, b),(e, a)}

Q:Determine the transitive closure R∗ of R. Express your answer as a set of ordered pairs.

Attempt =

```
{a,c}{c,e} = a,e
{a,e}{e,a} = a,a
{b,d}{d,b} = b,b
{c,e}{e,a} = {c,a}
{e,a}{a,c} = {a,c}

Transitive Closure = (a,e), (a,a), (b,b), (c,a), (a,c)
```

I'm not sure this is right though

Q2 is to find the partition of the set A into equivalence classes induced by R∗

> My attempt for this is  {a,c,e},{b},{d}

Not sure though

Comment: It is worth confirming the exact meanings of the words being used.  The meaning of "transitive closure" to me is in reference to the *relation* that is the minimal superset of the original relation who is transitive and so includes all of the original pairs in the relation as well... not just the pairs which needed to be added.

Comment: It is worth emphasizing as well the poor phrasing of the question... one might assume that every transitive closure induces a partition into equivalence classes given the way this is phrased.  That is simply untrue.  You would require the resulting relation to be symmetric and reflexive as well which *have a chance* of being true after looking at the transitive closure but might not necessarily be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed $(c,c),\ (d,d),\ (e,e)$ and $(e,c)$ and you also need to include the original pairs of $R$ in the transitive closure.
You can systematically write up all the *paths*, on each possible starting point.

The equivalence classes are $\{a,c,e\}$ and $\{b,d\}$.